# Get a block type of a page Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.4

I would like to know how to find the block type of some page example : the home page.

I have a problem in my homepage, I want to display some block, in the xml I declared my block in `<cms_index_index>` (local.xml) but if I put it in the `<reference name="head">` it appears, if  `<reference name="content">` or `<reference name="content">` it does not work . It seems to me that the type of block is not good.

xml:

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

in the homepage 1column-full.phtml i called it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seconnecter_test');?>
```

Comment: Solution : $this->getBlockHtml('name_block');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" output="toHtml" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: use output="toHtml" to make your block as an output block, only the output blocks are rendered automatically.

Comment: I tested this it works but it shows me the block at the bottom of the page while I want to display it in the middle after some block this is why I wanted to use reference name="root" and the get child in the phtml.

Comment: You can use the before/after attribute in block definition.

Comment: i have use before="content" or before="header" it doesn't work

Comment: let me know your block name, after you want to show this block.

Comment: after slider witch its locate in package/theme/template/child.phtml of after the menu package/theme/template/megamenu.phtml

Comment: ah, sorry but i dont know the name of this name, i know that the phtml who i want to display my custom block "seconnecter_test" is 1_column_full.phtml and this phtml is displayed in the home page, if i echo something in this phtml it apears in the home page but <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seconnecter_test');?> doesn't appear

Comment: read https://blog.philwinkle.com/the-most-misunderstood-concept-in-magento/

Comment: If my answer help you little bit, please upvote the answer pls.

Comment: I found a solution, to display my block in my home page i used: $this->getBlockHtml('name_block'); i dont know why getChildHtml('') dont work in content and work in header.

Answer (score 0):

When you give `<reference name="content">` Their block type is `core/text_list`. this block type output their content automatically, you don't need to use `getchildhtml()`.

In your **local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
   <cms_index_index>
     <reference name="content">
       <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" before="_" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
     </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
 </layout>
```

Place the template file at correct location, and the block will render at top of content.

Or try this go to `cms->pages->homepage` from admin panel. Add following in the layout update xml of design section

```
  <reference name="content">
       <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" before="_" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
   </reference>
```

refresh the cache.

Comment: I tested this and it does not work !. I used the solution of Suman Singh but it shows me the block at the bottom while I want to display it in the middle after some block this is why I wanted to use reference name="root" and the get child in the phtml.

Comment: you can put getchildhtml() call where you want.

Comment: Yes but your solution does not display anything, I used the output="toHtml" with the getChildHtml it works but it shows me the block down the footer and I dont want this, i want to display it in the place of the getChildHtml.

Comment: i have not this page and I dont want to go through the admin